# SharePoint 2010 Development Environment

Tags: development

I am an experienced C# developer.
I do not have access to a 64bit windows 7 machine to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 and other required software to build a development environment to play around and learn SharePoint.
I was wondering if there are any hosted Development environment that I can remote desktop into. I am looking for a free hosted development environment or something nominally priced.

Virtual images/VHD are ruled for the same OS limitation.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [CloudShare](http://go.cloudshare.com/). They have SharePoint VMs with Visual Studio, and [14 day trial](http://go.cloudshare.com/registration).

Please note: I am not affiliated with this company, just a happy customer.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, although this is a bit more expensive than what I was looking for.

Comment: You CAN install Sharepoint on Oracle VirtualBox.  It will run 64bit.  VirtualBox is open-source and free.  The cost would be the license for your Operating System.  Maybe that is better than an online hosted operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation. What sort of machine do you have? I've had some success (it works fine but is slow) running the sharepoint information worker image in VirtualBox. Virtual box allows a 64bit guest on a 32bit host OS, subject to certain hardware restrictions.

Check out this blog post on getting the information worker image running in virtual box.

http://rollyperreaux.com/2011/03/update-how-to-use-virtualbox-for-hyper-v-preconfigured-vm-images-graphical-step-by-step-part-1-of-4/

Comment: This is a good post.

Answer (score 0):

This post gives some good insights in [Building a SharePoint 2010 Development machine](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/Building%20a%20SharePoint%202010%20Development%20machine.aspx). (Also check out the links at the end of the article).